# Not able to use npm install to install angular-seed from github

Tags: node.js, angular

These Were the instruction on github

'-----------------

angular2-seed

A simple starter project demonstrating the basic concepts of Angular 2.

Usage

Clone or fork this repository
Make sure you have node.js installed version 5+
Make sure you have NPM installed version 3+
WINDOWS ONLY run npm install -g webpack webpack-dev-server typescript to install global dependencies
run npm install to install dependencies
run npm start to fire up dev server
open browser to http://localhost:3000
if you want to use other port, open package.json file, then change port in --port 3000 script

'-------------

I get the error saying package.json file not found, but I have package.json file on the folder please help. please see the link error message to see the errors in cmd prompt

Error message:
[image: error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed.git your-proj-name

cd your-proj-name

npm install

npm install -g webpack webpack-dev-server typescript

npm start
```

open browser then navigate to localhost:3000

for beginner, I'm prefer Angular CLI https://github.com/angular/angular-cli